# Having trouble proving that this set is a group under matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that the set of 2x2 matrices $X$, with $det(X) \neq 0$ is a group under matrix multiplication.

The first step for me is to prove closure.

Given $X = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$ and $X' = \begin{bmatrix}
a' & b'\\
c' & d'
\end{bmatrix}$ \begin{align}
    det(XX') &= det(\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a' & b'\\c' & d'\end{bmatrix})\\
            &= det(\begin{bmatrix}
            aa' + bc' & ab' + bd'\\
            ca' + dc' & cb' + dd'
            \end{bmatrix})\\
            &= (aa' + bc')(cb' + dd') - (ab' + bd')(ca' + dc')\\
            &= (aa'dd' - ab'dc) + (bc'cb - bd'ca')\\
            &= ad(a'd' - b'c) + bc(c'b - d'a)
\end{align}

However, I am not too sure how to go from here. I know that $det(X) = ad - bc \neq 0$ and $det(X') = a'd' - b'c' \neq 0$, but I'm not too sure how to utilize those properties to go further to prove that $det(AB) \neq 0$.

Comment: A well known property of determinants is that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. Are you not familiar with it? If not, I think it shouldn't be a big problem to check this property directly for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that\begin{align}0&\ne\det(X)\det(Y)\\&=(ad-bc)(a'd'-b'c')\\&=aa'dd'+bb'cc'-a'bcd'-ab'c'd\\&=(aa'+bc')(b'c+dd')-(ab'+bd')(a'c+c'd)\\&=\det(XY).\end{align}More generally, you always have $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with the same sizes.